# How do I share Databricks Spark Notebook report/dashboard with customers?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, databricks

I have been using zeppelin for few  months now. It is a great tool for internal data analytics. I am looking for more features for sharing the report with the customers. I need to send weekly/monthly/quarterly report to the customers. Looking for a way to automate this process. 
Please let me know if Databricks Spark Notebook or any other tool has features to help me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use databricks dashboard for this. Once you have the dashboard, you can do an HTML export of the dashboard and share the HTML file to the public.

If you're interested in automating the reporting process, you may want to look into databricks REST API: https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-export. You need to pass the `run_id` of the notebook job and the desired `views_to_export` (this value should be `DASHBOARD`) as the query parameters. Note that this run export only supports notebook jobs exports only, which is fine cos dashboards are usually generated from notebook jobs.

If your databricks HTML dashboard export is successful, you'll get a `"views"` JSON response which consists of a list of key-value pair objects, your HTML string will be available under the `"content"` key in each of the objects. You can then do anything with this HTML string, you can send it directly to email/slack for automatic reporting.

In order to generate a `run_id`, you first need to create a notebook job, which you can do via databricks UI. Then, you can get the `run_id` by triggering the notebook job to run by either:

1. using databricks scheduler, or
2. using the databricks run job now REST API: https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#run-now .

I preferred using the 2nd method, and run the job programmatically via REST API, because I can always find the `run_id` when I run the job, unlike the first method where I have to look at the databricks UI each time the job is scheduled to run. Either way, you must wait for the notebook job run to finish before running the notebook job export in order to get the complete databricks dashboard in HTML successfully.

Comment: This was as unhelpful as it was on the databricks site. Can you post some sample curl? That would all be at the #run-now link though and doesn't work if you don't have a run_id. https://forums.databricks.com/questions/11942/automatic-exporting-of-dashboard.html

Comment: @cloudsurfin Yes, I mentioned in my answer that run_id is required in order to export jobs as a Dashboard HTML. I had mentioned example ways of generating run_id above

Comment: I've written an article that explains this in more detail https://medium.com/@nicoej/visualize-databricks-dashboards-in-tableau-eae01b5c7219